# Display: flex thinking it is display: block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In all my years of coding I have never come across something so ridiculous in my entire life as I have with what I am seeing on my screen right now.

I have implemented a `display:flex` property, with the code below:

```
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.children{
  padding-inline: 15px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 66.6666%;
  max-width: 66.666%;
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-container parent--padding-block">
    <div class="children">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Two questions:

1. Why can I not horizontally shrink my `children` element via the `flex-basis: 66.6666%;`. Why is my browser completely ignoring this command? Maybe it's got it in it's "head" that it's a `display:block` which tells the element to span the entire width of the viewport?

I can adjust the width when the `flex-direction:row` by `flex-basis`, just not when `flex-direction:column`. Why is that?

2. Take a look at the below image:

[Non-existent issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsHIF.png)

[children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7XfN.png)

I'm sorry but I am genuinely at a loss for words here. Why on earth would I have this message when I have told it to be a `flex` item and not `block` item.

I have no other CSS attributes overriding these.

What on earth is going on?

I tried vertically shrinking the `children` element, and I expected it to do as it was told.

Comment: Your CSS is working, when you specify `flex-direction: column` to your flexbox, the `flex-basis` for its children is corresponding to their `height` but not `width`. Also the reason its showing `display: block` is probably you're inspecting the `.children` element but not `.flex-container`. But ultimately, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Shuo No, tag selectors do not overwrite class selectors.

Comment: @Shuo, how is it block when it literally says `display:flex`? It makes no sense.

Comment: @HaoWu I want to achieve the ability for my `children` to shrink horizontally so they don't take up the whole width of the viewport, but apparent my imagination is telling me that it's a `display: flex` so who knows?

Comment: My bad, but the working display is block in `div` at the top of img, I found other people has same problem, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079184/how-to-override-the-user-agent-styling)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I not horizontally shrink my `children` element via the `flex-basis: 66.6666%;`

When you specify `flex-direction: column` to your flexbox, the `flex-basis` for its children is corresponding to their `height` but not `width`. Thus `flex-basis: 66.6666%` is telling all `.children` to take `66.6666%` of their parent's HEIGHT initially, but the height of their parent `.flex-container` is undetermined, so it does nothing.

> Why is my browser completely ignoring this command? Maybe it's got it in it's "head" that it's a `display:block` which tells the element to span the entire width of the viewport?

The reason its showing `display: block` is probably you're inspecting the `.children` element but not `.flex-container`. And it is not taking the whole width because you specified `max-width: 66.666%;` to them, I marked them red borders to see it clearly.

[image]

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.children {
  padding-inline: 15px;
  /* these are unnecessary */
  /*
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 66.6666%;
  */
  width: 66.666%;
  max-width: 66.666%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container parent--padding-block">
  <div class="children">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but why has it now gone to the left and not stayed centred, like I told it to `justify-content: center;`?

Comment: Because with `flex-direction: column`, the main axis is not horizontal anymore, you need to use `align-items: center` to center them horizontally. I have updated the answer. If you want them to take `66.6666%` space horizontally, add `width: 66.6666%` as well.